# VB to C# rewriting question

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, translation

I have a following method declaration in VB and need to translate it into C#:

```
<DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint:="OpenPrinterW", _
   SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, _
   ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
Public Shared Function OpenPrinter(ByVal src As String, ByRef hPrinter As IntPtr, ByVal pd As Int16) As Boolean
End Function
```

Particularly I am not sure if it the `ByRef` argument specifier is equivalent to `ref` is C#.
Also I don't know if `Shared == static` and whether it must be `extern`.
Probably lot of you are proficient in both VB and C#, so I'd be grateful for providing correct declaration in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check signature here:
http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winspool/OpenPrinter.html

Answer (score 1):

Using this ["translator"](http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/CodeTranslator/):

```
[DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="OpenPrinterW", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern bool OpenPrinter(string src, ref IntPtr hPrinter, Int16 pd) {
}
```

I hope this helps.

Thanks,
Damian

Comment: This isn’t correct. At the very least, it’s missing the `extern` and has one method body too many.

Comment: @Konrad: You're right. Without more context, the translator does not know the implementation is external, as it does not take DllImport as "seriously" as it should. Editing to correct.

Answer (score 1):

> Particularly I am not sure if it the `ByRef` argument specifier is equivalent to `ref` is C#.
>   Also I don't know if `Shared` == `static` and whether it must be `extern`.

Yes, all of these assumtions are correct:

```
[DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="OpenPrinterW",
   SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
   ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern bool OpenPrinter(string src, ref IntPtr hPrinter, Int16 pd);
```

(In fact, `ByRef` can correspond to either `ref` or `out` but since I don’t know which is required here I’m going with the more general `ref` – this is guaranteed to work).

Answer (score 0):

A great translation tool is the .NET reflector. Use it to reverse engineer an EXE or DLL into various languages: http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

VB

```
Class Demo
    <DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint:="OpenPrinterW", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling:=True,CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Public Shared Function OpenPrinter(ByVal src As String, ByRef hPrinter As IntPtr, ByVal pd As Int16) As Boolean
    End Function
End Class
```

C#

```
internal class Demo
{
    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="OpenPrinterW", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true)]
    public static extern bool OpenPrinter(string src, ref IntPtr hPrinter, short pd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterW", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern bool OpenPrinter(string src, ref IntPtr hPrinter, Int16 pd);
```

There is a good conversion tool here, it doesn't handle everything, but it is pretty good.

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/